# How can someone use conditional formatting based on the cell in the sheet itself dynamically?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I am currently trying to use conditional formatting for my classes and I want to highlight a row of cells if the value in a specific column is equal to the value in a specific cell. If you see in the picture, the following is my thought process:

1. The applicable range is from A:G (121 because that ends the sheet)
2. Custom formula is `=$G3=I16` which I believe to search the entire column G (Course Names) and if it is equal to the value of I16 (Specific course name from a key) then highlight it red. However, when running it, only 2 random cells get highlighted as shown in the screenshot.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible and if so, where my thought process was wrong? Thank you in advance!

I already tried manipulating some of the values:

```
=$G$3=I16
=$G3=I17
=$G3=INDIRECT(I16)
```

It does work if I use the value of the cell itself (ie., Women of Christian East, Consumer Behaviors, etc.) instead of the cell. Please note I am also not too familiar with the indirect function!

I also tried to play with the actual cell values to see if it was not referencing the text so I created an IF statement in the sheet which returned true. I wasn't sure what else to try beyond formula manipulation but I am happy to answer any other questions and add more as needed. [Table showing all of the raw data. Data is sorted in order of soonest date to latest date. Column I shows the courses as a key value pair and is colored coded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIhkx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not random cells are highlighted, but according to your rules. First, your range is `A1:G121` and formula starts at `G3`, so it looks for condition at `G3` ant applies it to `A1`, then looks at `G4` and applies it to `A2` and so on. Second, value you compare to must have absolute reference, so it doesn't "move" for each cell in range you are applying to.
Try formula:

```
=$G3=$I$16
```

Applied to range:

```
A3:G121
```

Result:

[image]

Also take a read: [absolute vs relative reference](https://www.w3schools.com/googlesheets/google_sheets_rel_ref.php)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I never thought about the distinguishment between the absolute and relative reference in the actual value being looked as opposed to where it was initially looking so this helped a TON! Thank you so much for the explanation. :-)